# Loading Javascript files sequentially in <body> and fire callback on completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an weebsite (Cordova/Phonegap app actually) that currently has in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appPolyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appLibs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

This works fine, but actually the website scripts are quite heavy, so while the scripts are parsed, the html of the page is actually not displayed.

I want the HTML of the page to be displayed, and only then load the scripts above.

I know I can load the scripts in the `<body>` tag, but in my case I must absolutly load these scripts sequentially.

So basically what I want is:

- Make the HTML display immediately on startup before loading any script
- Load the scripts sequentially in body
- Be notified when the last script (app.js) is loaded, so that I can start the app (as the document ready event has already fired, I need another one)

Is this possible?

I can accept a JQuery based solution but prefer raw javascript.

Comment: completion callback is `ready`

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup (See `async` and `defer` part).

Comment: why can't you just place your script tags at the bottom of your html body and register a window.onload handler to start your application after the page has loaded completely including all resources like scripts ?

Comment: @AndréR I don't think putting the `<script>` in the body will preserve the loading order like in `head` right?

Comment: @EricMartinez ... very good post to read !

Comment: @SebastienLorber ... the browser will execute all scripts in the order they appear in the document. (see the Stackoverflow link Eric Martinez posted) . So placing the scripts at the bottom of the body should work. But i like the comment EricMartinez posted. Using 'defer' should solve your problem and increase performance at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the script-tags after the body and 
you can place an own script after the included scripts

```
...
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appPolyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appLibs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script>
    starttheapp();   // call function when "app.js" is ready
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Is the loading order of the guaranteed even in the <body> tag?

Comment: the loading order is in and outside the body-Tag the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use **defer** in your  tag to delay loading this script after the body is loaded
or use **async** to load while loading the body

```
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="appPolyfills.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="appLibs.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: it may work but how can I know the last (app.js) has finished loading?

Comment: async will not preserve the loading order